# Streaming .mp4 File to http server

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm trying to stream a mp4 file to my http-server written in python. I'm using ffmpeg to stream it from the client with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -s 640x480 -i video.mp4 -f mpeg1video -b 800k -r 30 http://localhost:9999
```

Whenever i execute this command, i get the following warning / error:

```
Option video_size not found.
```

Tried googling it, but wasn't able to found a working solution, most of them said I need to include the -s tag, which i already did, still getting the error tho. Does anyone know a fix for that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work

```
ffmpeg  -i 1590.mp4  -f mpeg1video -b:v   -r 30 http://localhost:9999
```